# background processes and outputting to file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that does the following.

```
spinner()
{
    local pid=$1
    local delay=0.75
    local spinstr='\|/-'
    while [ "$(ps a | awk '{print $1}' | grep $pid)" ]; do
        local temp=${spinstr#?}
        printf " [%c]  " "$spinstr"
        local spinstr=$temp${spinstr%"$temp"}
        sleep $delay
        printf "\b\b\b\b\b\b"
    done
    printf "    \b\b\b\b"
}

printf "Testing for timestamps,please wait..." | tee test_report.txt

(process_1 -f $FILENAME test_1 >> test_report.txt 2>&1)&
spinner $!

printf "\n"

printf "Testing for accurate seq numbers,please wait..." | tee test_report.txt

(process_2 -f $FILENAME sequence >> test_report.txt 2>&1) &
spinner $!
printf "\n";
```

However when I open the test_report.txt I see only the output of `'process_2'` and can't see the output of `'process_1'`

I guess the question really is what happens to a the output file that contains the stdout of a background process.?

Comment: By the way, 'kill -0 $pid' is a safe, great way to check if a pid is still active.  It does not actually signal the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tee test_report.txt` is overwriting it.  Try `tee -a test_report.txt`